# java EE and cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova, jakarta-ee

I want to integrate [quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) into cordova application, I've create simple test file like this:

```
import com.caucho.quercus.Quercus;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Quercus interpreter = new Quercus();
        interpreter.execute("echo 'foo';");
    }
}
```

but if fail to compile because it require java EE and I have only open jdk   8 installed when I use `umake` to install all that require to create android app for cordova.

Will I be able to run java EE on android? If yes what I need to install to compile java EE test application and cordova app?

Here is a list of classes that throw error when I run javac:

```
import javax.annotation.sql.DataSourceDefinition;
import javax.annotation.sql.DataSourceDefinitions;
import javax.cache.Cache;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.EJBs;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.el.ELResolver;
import javax.el.ExpressionFactory;
import javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException;
import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;
import javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.enterprise.context.NormalScope;
import javax.enterprise.context.spi.Context;
import javax.enterprise.context.spi.Contextual;
import javax.enterprise.context.spi.CreationalContext;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Alternative;
import javax.enterprise.inject.AmbiguousResolutionException;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Any;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Disposes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.IllegalProductException;
import javax.enterprise.inject.InjectionException;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.enterprise.inject.New;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Specializes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Annotated;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.AnnotatedField;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.AnnotatedMethod;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.AnnotatedParameter;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.AnnotatedType;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Decorator;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionTarget;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InterceptionType;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Interceptor;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.PassivationCapable;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ProcessAnnotatedType;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ProcessBean;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ProcessInjectionTarget;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ProcessProducer;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Producer;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Stereotype;
import javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Provider;
import javax.inject.Qualifier;
import javax.inject.Scope;
import javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
```

Comment: Java EE is something well over and above JDK 8.   You'd need a Java EE app server OR a way to package the necessary JARs in your Android package.  Surely Quercus can't require the entire Java EE spec.  Are there particular pieces that it's asking for?  Sounds too heavyweight to me.

Comment: @duffymo there are 58 errors with import when I run javac, all from javax, here is a list https://pastebin.com/aqGJU5tM

Comment: I can't look at that link.  Sorry - blocked where I am.  I'd add dependencies in my Maven pom.xml until the compilation errors went away.

Comment: @duffymo added to the question

Comment: Sorry, this sounds like the wrong way to go for an Android app.  Too heavy; unnecessary.  The world has moved on from EJBs and Java EE.  You should think about that, too.  If you can't, keep adding dependencies to your pom.xml until the errors are resolved.  I see seven; won't be difficult.

Comment: I don't have pom.xml file, I'm using cordova app that converted to apk.

Comment: Add the dependencies manually.  I assumed you used Maven.